# Использование TODO

Tags: java, javadoc

Решили попробовать использовать `// TODO` для некрупных правок в проекте, но обнаружили, что TODO по коду и так много, оказалось, существует `// FIXME`, подскажите, может быть есть какой-нибудь способ, обозначить кому именно это предназначено, например `// FIXME @programmerName`

Comment: какой редактор используете? во многих редакторах есть распознование TODO и можете воспользоватся ими

Comment: Eclipse, дело в том, что, хотим использовать эти аннотации, как вещи, который нужно сейчас по-быстрому поправить.

Comment: Я понимаю, что в Eclipse это может и не поможет, но в Android Studio есть фильтр по тегам комментариев, то есть можно отфильтровать только то, что касается, к примеру, тебя.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть вариант такой

В меню **Window | Preferences | PHP | Editor | Task Tags** (для `java` *Java -> Compiler -> Task tags*) открывается редактор

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добавьте в списке теги с разработчиками VANYA, FEDYA и др.

И когда используете комменатрий укажите 2 тега

```
// TODO VANYA сделай это
```

или

```
// FIXME  FEDYA сделай то
```

для JSP

Думаю самый легкий вариант

Как найти теперь задачи?

**Window → Show View → Tasks**

Comment: Интересно. А не подскажите, как в представлении Tasks(или ещё где-то) найти все задания для // TODO VANYA?

Comment: для `eclips` будет `Window → Show View → Tasks`

Comment: Отлично, решили на том, что разработчик ставит все // TODO со своим именем на высокий приоритет и сразу в представлении их видно.

Comment: Отлично работает для JS и JAVA, не знаете, подобное в JSP можно как-то сделать?

Comment: `Window->Preferences` выбираем `General->Editors->Structured Text Edit->Task Tags`  находим `Enable searching for Task Tags` и делаем `JSP` активным

Answer (score 3):

Мне кажется когда возникают такие вопросы, есть смысл подумать о внедрении JIRA. Ей можно пользоваться отдельно, но она также легко интегрируется с Eclipse. Там уже будет централизовано видно кто что должен сделать или уже сделал и вообще когда что-нибудь делал.